# Calling method available in the activity

Tags: android, method-invocation

I am trying to call a method available in a `Activity` from a java file.

The calling is made fine and the control transfers to the function by this code in the java file.

```
  myActivity my = new myActivty();
  myActivity.method1();
```

Now my problem is i cant able to give a `toast` message or display the `alertdialog`, Its giving null pointer exception when im using the `Toast` message,

```
07-20 15:13:00.836: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(418): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Am i doing right?

Where am i wrong?

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast needs Context to show up. You're trying to show toast but you have created Activity without Context. Pass instance of working Activity to create dialog or show toast.

Answer (score 0):

:) This wont work. You will need to pass some kind of a reference from your activity to the other Java class.

More in this here http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/741caff5a9536859?pli=1